# How to manage ports for rootless podman container running in rootless podman container?

Tags: podman

I am trying to run a rootless podman container inside a rootless podman container but can not get the port-forwarding to work.
First, I started a podman container with podman installed inside:

```
podman run -it --name podman -u podman --rm quay.io/containers/podman
```

Then, I tried starting a MySQL container inside that container with:

```
podman run -p 8000:33060 -d -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=abc docker.io/mysql
```

However, the MySQL server is available at port 33060 of the first container and is not forwarded to port 8000. Trying to start, e.g., an nginx container fails because it can not bind to port 80. It seems that the inner container is directly using the ports of the outer container and does not have it's own network namespace (if that's the correct term).

How do I have to configure podman to run the inner container with its own network namespace?